# Shell script to assign values from a lookup table is too slow

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, awk, string

I'm trying to assign some variables from a lookup file with a shell script.
I have something working but it seems unnecessary slow.

Script:

```sh
while read line           
    do           
        code=`echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`;
        device=`echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'`;
        state=`echo $line | awk -F' ' '{print $3}'`;
        if  [[ $code == $message ]]
            then
                echo "Translated: $device-$state";
        fi
done <CODE-LIST.txt
```

CODE-LIST.txt:

```
MQTT-CODE   DEVICE  STATE
1-1-32-16236607 RGB_LED ON
1-1-32-16203967 RGB_LED OFF
```

Is there a faster way to do this? (Maybe awk or sed)
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
while read code device state junk; do
    if [[ $code == $message ]]; then
        echo "Translated: $device-$state"
    fi
done <CODE-LIST.txt
```

Using extra processes (i.e. forking awk every time) will slow it down a lot. `read` will read multiple fields, separated by `$IFS` (default value is all white space). The last variable listed will receive the rest of the line, if any.

I'm just wondering where `$message` is supposed to come from. Outside the code snippet perhaps?

EDIT:
If the code part will only occur once in the input, then you can `break` out of the loop once it's been found; that will speed things up as well.

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew I was over doing it a bit. Your answer helped me a lot. Not just with the problem, but with understanding, too.

Answer (score 6):

Could use awk for the whole thing.
Awk is also far quicker than `while read` loops.

```
awk -vM="$Message" '$1==M{print "Translated:",$2"-"$3}' CODE-LIST.txt
```

#### Explanation

```
    -vM="$Message" - Create a variable named M with the value from $Message

     $1==M         - If the first field is equal to variable M($Message)

     {print "Translated:",$2"-"$3} - Write Translated and the second and third fields

     CODE-LIST.txt - The file being read
```

#### More notes on the code

A `,` is used in conjunction with print to print the OFS(Output field separator) which by default is space
.
Unless specified differently, the code will be run on each line of the file by default.
.
The print command will add the ORS(output record separator) to the end of the string it prints. This by default is a newline.

Comment: As he is new to scripting it may be helpful to provide explaination of this `awk` code.

Comment: @geedoubleya happy ?